# Multi-site authentification "google like"

Tags: authentication, design-patterns, database-design, architecture

I want to create multiple services, which support an SSO (Single Sign-On) service.

To simplify, a google like services. With a single account you can use all services (and you log in once).

I found many ideas, but I want to have some opinions on how to design these services, and which technologies are the most adequate:

- many or one database ??
- creating an auth api ??
- sharing session ?
- using nosql databse or not ?
- duplicate user information foreach database ?
- separate users tables on a single database ?
- node js vs php !!
- ...

**Update**

I know this is opinion based (I ask for your opinions), I wish to have different proposition of design patterns.

It's purely theorique, so I can understand how it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally opinion based, and will likely be closed.  But...

Don't write your own auth service.  There are many good packages out there, and very few people are really qualified to write authentication and authorization platforms.  If you really don't want to use a pre-packaged solution, at least use one of them as a template.

[Here is a good list of SSO solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations), pick one or two and give them a try.  Many are free and open-source.  I have had luck with OpenAM, but many others are also very good.